# Integral Comparison of a Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Careful examination of the proof of the lemma on Integral Comparison of a Series given in the
lectures will reveal that, if $f : [1, \infty) \to \Bbb R^+$ is a nonincreasing function and $1 < n < m$ then

Prove that

$$\sum_{k=n}^{m+1}f(k) \ge \int_n^m f(x)dx$$

and that

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}f(k) \le \int_n^m f(x)dx$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\int_{n}^{m}f(x)dx&=\sum_{i=n}^{m-1}\int_{i}^{i+1}f(x)dx\\
&\leq\sum_{i=n}^{m-1}\int_{i}^{i+1}f(i)dx\\
&=\sum_{i=n}^{m-1}f(i),
\end{align*}
I think the upper index can be sharpen to $m-1$.